# redux-observable: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-observable

I have a problem with my epic, please help me find out where I went wrong. Thank you!

The following code leads me to the error:

```html
const loginEpic = (action$) =>
  action$
    .ofType('LOGIN')
    .switchMap(() => {
      return Observable.fromPromise(loginService())
        .map((result) => {
          return Observable.of({
            payload: result,
            type: types.loginCompleted,
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          return Observable.of({
            payload: error,
            type: types.loginFailed,
          });
        });
    });
```

And here is my configureStore file:

```html
const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware(rootEpic);

// Ref: https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/recipes/HotModuleReplacement.html
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./epic', () => {
    const nextEpic = require('./epic');
    epicMiddleware.replaceEpic(nextEpic);
  });
}

const configureStore = (): Store<any> => {

  const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(epicMiddleware)));
  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./reducer', () => {
      const nextReducer = require('./reducer').default;
      store.replaceReducer(nextReducer);
    });

    return store;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you must drop the `Observable.of(...)` from within the `map()` (**EDIT - thanks to paulpdaniels:** but not the `catch()`) method, because in this way you are returning an observable of observables - see the simplified code below:

```
Observable.fromPromise(...)
    .map(result => Observable.of(...))  // maps an object to an observable
```

The entire code should be:

```
const loginEpic = (action$) =>
  action$
    .ofType('LOGIN')
    .switchMap(() => {
      return Observable.fromPromise(loginService())
        .map((result) => {
          return {
            payload: result,
            type: types.loginCompleted,
          };
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          return Observable.of({
            payload: error,
            type: types.loginFailed,
          });
        });
    });
```

Comment: You overshot, correct to remove from `map`, but `catch` requires an `Observable` return.

Comment: @paulpdaniels Yes, absolutely right, thank you for the correction!

Comment: Oh I didn't recognize it. Thank you ;)

Comment: @paulpdaniels yes, in my case I fixed it like this:.catch((err: any, caught: Observable<any>) => {
          return Observable.of({
            payload: err,
            type: types.loginFailed,
          });
        }));

Comment: not working for me. I am still getting the same error